Negative zero values - Power BI
Why Power BI visual shows negative zero amount? The specific mesaure is formated as "Currency" at 2 decimal places. I have also filter out anything with zero but these values remain.

Any help will be appreciated.

This is probably a precision issue. You are only showing two decimal places but the value could be -0.001. Use a rounding function in your measure.
